# Alternative ways to post to Google+ Page?

Tags: google-plus, post

Are there any alternative ways available to post to a **Google+ Page** such as email or text message?

Comment: http://www.computerworlduk.com/how-to/applications/3308148/how-to-post-to-google-by-email/ ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Otherwise you'll have people dropping links to single sources in their answers like below. Do you want to post from a web application, an API, or other? Are you looking for one method or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like HootSuite to post to your Google+ page.

Answer (score 1):

You can send posts using SMS (text messages) as documented here:
http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1304843&hlrm=en&answer=1304920

Answer (score 0):

There are [Google+ SMS commands](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1304843&hlrm=en&answer=1304920) available, but other than that, Google has not opened up their API to third-party clients, like [Buffer](http://bufferapp.com/), which works for Facebook and Twitter.